# Leave Parts of Formula inactive in partial Differentiation

Tags: differentials

for thermodynamics, I would like to use a thermodynamic derivative 
$$ 
\frac 1 T=\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\Bigg \vert_V 
$$i.e. the derivative of the entropy S with respect to the energy E with the volume kept constant. 
In this context I tried to differentiate as follows (subsituting E to Z since E is protected)

```
    V[Z_]:=Z^6;
    S[Z_]:=V[Z]^2-Z;

    TemperatureDef=1/T==D[S,Z]
```

How do I differentiate S with respect to Z without V[Z] being evaluated (i.e. plugged in)?

The result should read -1 instead of -1+12 Z^11

Comment: Please don't use underscores (a.k.a. `Blank`) in variable names: They have its own meaning in Mathematica (They are used to build patterns.)

Comment: You can try something like this: `ClearAll[V];S = V[Z]^2 - Z;
1/T == D[S, Z]`

Comment: The function `Dt` might also be useful

Comment: Related [meta post about moving goalposts](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-to-avoid-and-what-to-do-with-ops-moving-the-goalposts-in-the-comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make the dependence explicit:

```
S[V_, Z_] := V^2 - Z
V[Z_] := Z^6
```

Then:

```
Derivative[0, 1][S][V[Z], Z]
```

> -1

Answer (score 2):

*Update: Answer to changed question:*

See below for some discussion.

```
Block[{V},
 SetAttributes[V, Constant];
 S'[V]
 ]
(*  -1  *)
```

Note that if you change `S =..` to `S[Z_] :=..`, you should change `D[S,Z]` to `D[S[Z],Z]`, which is equivalent to `S'[Z]` above.

*Answer to original question:*

Perhaps one of these methods will get you started.  First, though, you have to `Clear` your previous definitions.  `Set` (`=`) does not set up equations but makes symbols represent the values of the right-hand side at the time of definition. Hence `S=V^2-Z` makes `S` equal `Z^12 - Z`, and the value for `S` contains no instance of `V`.

```
ClearAll[S, V, Z];
```

1. Setting temporarily the attribute [`Constant`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Constant.html):

```
Block[{V},
 SetAttributes[V, Constant];
 D[V^2 - Z, Z]]
(*  -1  *)
```

2. Using the option [`Constants`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Constants.html) of `Dt`:

```
Dt[S]/Dt[Z] /. 
 First@Solve[
   Dt[{S == V^2 - Z}, Constants -> {V}] /. 
    Verbatim[Dt][x_, ___] :> Dt[x], {Dt[S]}]
(*  -1  *)
```

Or this way seems a little cleaner:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Dt},
 SetOptions[Dt, Constants -> {V}];
 Dt[S]/Dt[Z] /. First@Solve[Dt[{S == V^2 - Z}], {Dt[S]}]
 ]
(*  -1  *)
```

Comment: Ok, that works as long as V is indeed a constant defined by set (=). But how does it work if it is S[Z_],V[Z_] ? Do you know a way to set functions temporarily to a constant?

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider That's not how the original question was set up, was it?

Answer (score 0):

A Little cludgy, but for temporary setting, try

```
V[Z_]=Z^6;
S[Z_]=V[Z]^2-Z;

Temperature_Def=1/T==D[(S[Z]),Z]/.D[V[Z]^2,Z]->0
(* 1/T==-1 )
```